# Custom CSS loading but not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, iis, https

I have deployed a dotnet application on IIS. HTTPS is used to access the URL. I am facing very strange situation where in CSS and jquery written by me are not working whereas those provided from jquery or bootstrap are working well. On checking into the developer tool I can see that files are getting loaded with status code 200.

I am using below code to access CSS.

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Assets/css/ate.css") %>' />
```

What could be the possible cause and how to resolve? Please help.

Comment: Check the relevant elements in the console. It may be that your styles are being applied, but are not specific enough to override the styling from Bootstrap

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its all good there. No errors. Also, while accessing the URL's on server I am able to see the css applied there as localhost but while accessing from remote machine with https URL this issue is happening. Apart from CSS, functionality is working well . Any help !!

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. You need to check the CSS that's *actually being applied* to the elements

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I looked into elements CSS, it might be the cause ! What to do in order to resolve this ?

Comment: You probably need to make the CSS selectors you use more specific, eg change `.bar { color: red; }` to `p span#foo .bar { color: red; }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My question is how is it working in localhost perfectly ? Why this issue is coming when access using machine name URL

Comment: I can't answer that. You haven't shown nearly enough information

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I looked and compared with the Correct and Wrong rendered page and got to see that there is a css class from bootstrap which is rendered like `::after, ::before` in correct while `:before` and `:after` differently in wrong pages. Any reason why is it rendering like this ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got the issue, my IE was set to be IE7, when I updated it to Use EDGE it's working well. Thanks for your suggestion's.